# How to Access the "ows_owshiddenversion" property of sharepoint calendar list in c#?

Tags: caml-query, sharepoint-calendar

here I am trying to Access the **ows_owshiddenversion** i.e **Hidden** property of sharepoint calendar list as like below code.

```
 CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
                camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>" +
                                  "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                                  "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                                  "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Now /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
                                  "</Where></Query></View>";



                ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

                clientContext.Load(collListItem);

                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
                {
                    var Title = oListItem["Title"] != null ? oListItem["Title"].ToString() : "";
                    var EventDate = oListItem["EventDate"] != null ? oListItem["EventDate"].ToString() : "";
                    var EndDate = oListItem["EndDate"] != null ? oListItem["EndDate"].ToString() : "";
                    var Location = oListItem["Location"] != null ? oListItem["Location"].ToString() : "";
                    var Description = oListItem["Description"] != null ? oListItem["Description"].ToString() : "";
                    var guid = oListItem["GUID"] != null ? ListItem["GUID"].ToString() : "";
                    var created = oListItem["Created"];
                    var modified = oListItem["Modified"];
                    bool Event = Convert.ToBoolean(oListItem["fAllDayEvent"]);
                    var recurrenceData = oListItem["RecurrenceData"];
                    var Number = (int)oListItem["ows_owshiddenversion"];
}
```

but when I reached to the

```
var Number = (int)oListItem["ows_owshiddenversion"];** it gives me a Exception as
"+      Hidden  'oListItem.ParentList.Hidden' threw an exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException'   bool {Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException}
"
```

which I am unable to resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field's internal name is actually `owshiddenversion`. However, you'll likely need to add it as a ViewFields entry as well:

```
CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where>" +
                    "<DateRangesOverlap><FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceID\"/>" +
                    "<Value Type=\"DateTime\"><Now /></Value></DateRangesOverlap>" +
                    "</Where></Query>" +
                    "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"EventDate\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"EndDate\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Location\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Description\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"GUID\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Created\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"fAllDayEvent\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"RecurrenceData\" />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name=\"owshiddenversion\" />" +
                    "</ViewFields></View>";



ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.Load(collListItem);

clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
{
    var Title = oListItem["Title"] != null ? oListItem["Title"].ToString() : "";
    var EventDate = oListItem["EventDate"] != null ? oListItem["EventDate"].ToString() : "";
    var EndDate = oListItem["EndDate"] != null ? oListItem["EndDate"].ToString() : "";
    var Location = oListItem["Location"] != null ? oListItem["Location"].ToString() : "";
    var Description = oListItem["Description"] != null ? oListItem["Description"].ToString() : "";
    var guid = oListItem["GUID"] != null ? ListItem["GUID"].ToString() : "";
    var created = oListItem["Created"];
    var modified = oListItem["Modified"];
    bool Event = Convert.ToBoolean(oListItem["fAllDayEvent"]);
    var recurrenceData = oListItem["RecurrenceData"];
    var Number = (int)oListItem["owshiddenversion"];
}
```